# django using oauth2.0, getting error {"error": "invalid_grant"} when trying to get access token

Tags: django, oauth-2.0

Following this tutorial, https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html on step

`curl -X POST -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" "http://127.0.0.1:8000/o/token/" -d "client_id=${ID}" -d "client_secret=${SECRET}" -d "code=${CODE}" -d "code_verifier=${CODE_VERIFIER}" -d "redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/noexist/callback" -d "grant_type=authorization_code"`

I'm getting an error:

```
{"error": "invalid_grant"}
```

I have checked everything twice, and even re-assembled the app from the ground up as in tutorial, it still gives the error.

Please help, thank you!